# How to fill navbar height fully when I hover mouse pointer over a link?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor

Here I'm designing webpage for my personal project. I have this navbar added in my website, in which I wish to fill the links in navbar fully when I hover mouse pointer over those links. Here I have attached the screenshot of what I'm getting.

[image: Marked in red ink is the section which I'm unable to fill.]

The html code for navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container" style="overflow:auto">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">BookStore</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Books/Index">Books</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The CSS behind navbar:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
  /*margin-bottom: 60px;*/
}

nav {
    background-color: #8080ff;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar-nav {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Note: I'm designing the web app using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2022.

Tried to change margin properties of `nav` class, `body` class, `html` class. Tried to set `height` property to 100%. But nothing worked!!

Answer (score 2):

You should set `padding` to **0px** for the `nav` element:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #8080ff;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is the answer for "what does `!important` mean?"**

The `!important` rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal.

In fact, if you use the `!important` rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!

**example:**

```
#id {
  background-color: blue;
}

.class {
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

OR it will prioritize the CSS property. **!important** have the most priority than anything.

Answer (score 1):

add padding:0px !important to nav selector in CSS

Comment: It worked! GREAT!!
But what does ```!important``` mean?

Comment: The !important rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property than normal.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code

```
<style>
    li.nav-item{
        display: contents;
        padding: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    li.nav-item a{
        margin-right: 12px;
        
    }
    li.nav-item a:hover{
        background-color: #cccccc;
        /* display: contents; */
        padding: 16px;
        top: 0;
        /* position: absolute; */
    }
  
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #cccccc;
      margin: 0;
      /*margin-bottom: 60px;*/
    }
    
    nav {
        background-color: #8080ff;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    ul{
        margin-left: 60px !important;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container" style="overflow:auto">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">BookStore</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Books/Index">Books</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).